# Java Index out of bounds exception when printing a grid

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program that prints out domino objects from an array of them into a grid, however whenever I run it I get an index out of bounds exception. I can make a singular line that moves along and draws each domino in the array which works fine, but a grid causes the following:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at DominoGame.drawTable(DominoGame.java:182)
at DominoGame.redraw(DominoGame.java:258)
at DominoGame.restart(DominoGame.java:119)
at DominoGame.<init>(DominoGame.java:91)
at DominoGame.main(DominoGame.java:262)
```

Here is my code:

```
    public void drawTable(){
        int i = 0;
        if(this.table.isEmpty()){
        }
        else{
            for(int col = 0;col<this.table.size();col++){
                for(int row = 0;row<this.table.size();row++){
                    this.table.get(i).draw(TABLE_LEFT+DOMINO_SPACING*row, TABLE_TOP+DOMINO_HEIGHT*col);
                    if(this.table.get(i+1) != null){
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Many thanks for any help

EDIT: People have pointed out I had incorrect incrementation in my inner loop. I have fixed this, but I am still getting the error. Thanks

Comment: Please point out this line in your code `DominoGame.java:182`

Comment: Please add the code with declaration and initialization of this.table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `col` instead of `row` in your inner loop. Furthermore, you iterate over your table in a strange way: The outer loop iterates once over all elements with `col`, the inner loop does the same with `row` (with above mentioned typo), and additionally you have `i`, which will definitely grow bigger than table's size, and is used to get elements from `table`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that, but I'm still getting the error with the fixed incrementation, unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your variable "i" is supposed to be incremented at most col*row times, probably its value  eventually exceeds the size of table.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.table.get(i+1) //if i+1 does not exist and you want to call it, you get error
```

[Java Api - Methode get() in ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))

In the description you will see, in which situation the error will be thrown

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code:

```
if(this.table.get(i+1) != null){
   i++;
}
```

to

```
if (i < this.table.size()-1 && this.table.get(i+1) != null) {
   i++;
}
```

When i = this.table.size() - 1, this.table.get(i+1) will raise IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you help. Since my code needed a 7 wide grid, I was able to put this code together:

```
public void drawTable(){
    if(this.table.isEmpty()){
    }
    else{
        int rowCount = 0;
        int colCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<this.table.size();i++){
            if(i%7 == 0){
                rowCount++;
                colCount = 0;
            }
            this.table.get(i).draw(TABLE_LEFT+DOMINO_SPACING*colCount, TABLE_TOP+DOMINO_HEIGHT*rowCount); 
            colCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

This code accomplished what I want, printing 7 dominoes in one row, then moving to the next and printing another 7. This could be made to work for any grid size just with changing the 7 to another number.

I'd just like to thanks everyone again for your help, its made this process a bit less face-desk worthy than it otherwise would have been.